# How to run my Java Selenium program automatically every hour

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, selenium, automation

I have developed a test case in Java and Selenium webdriver. I have developed it in Eclipse IDE. Can you please tell me if i want to execute this code every hour how should i do it.
I dont use maven or anything else. And i have no idea how they work. All i do is click on the execute button in eclipse IDE. But i want to do this automatically instead of click on execute button in eclipse.
Please suggest.
This is wat i want to execute every hour:

```
wd.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        WebElement logo = wd.findElement(By.id("abc"));
        logo.click();
        try {
            getscreenshot();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Found an exception");
        }
    }
    static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh mm ss a");
    public static void getscreenshot() throws Exception
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("G:\\Screen Output"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".jpg"));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(now.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using cron? Assuming you are on a *NIX machine

Comment: Using Windows system. Thats where i would like to do this

Comment: How about using the Windows Task Scheduler to run your main Java program every hour?

Comment: can you suggest any tutorial/site which gives details instruction on doing it

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569 - WinXP
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7 - Win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should export your Java program to an executable `.jar` file

Right click on your project an choose Export

http://www.upimg.fr/ih/7qqx.png

Then choose Runnable JAR File click Next , choose your location  and export :

[image]

Then you create in the same directory as your `.jar` file a file named `name_of_program.bat`
You edit it with a notepad and write :

```
java -jar your_program.jar
pause
```

Finally you have to schedule a windows automated task to launch that `.bat` anytime you need.

See @HiteshDharmadasani links to do that :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Hi i have exported my jar file with the same name as my java file. Screenshot.bat
I didnot understand this step. can u put some screenshot pls.. 
Then you create in the same directory as your .jar file a file named name_of_program.bat You edit it with a notepad and write :

java -jar your_program.jar
pause

Comment: Create a text file and rename it `you_choose_a_name.bat` Then you write in that file what I have said before (java -jar ...)

Comment: What did you write in the `.bat` file ? And what files do you have in the same folder as the bat file ?

Comment: Hi i got it working. i had to specify the path in the .bat file along with the jar file name.. its working good now.. thank you :)